# make vuejs component wait for the variable to become available

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vue.js

I have an VueJS component that list the contents of the array to the page. `runner.availableResources.cores` and `runner.availableResources.memory` come from bus creates using`busmq` npm package. They take awhile to become available, about 15s depending on IO buffer and thus not immediately available when the page renders.

The error is: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cores' of undefined"`

How can I make Vue keep checking for values to become available?

```
<template>
  <b-col>
    <b-table striped hover :items="formatRunners"></b-table>
  </b-col>
</template>

<script>
const fileSize = require("filesize");
export default {
  name: "RunnersList",
  props: {
    runners: Array
  },
  computed: {
    formatRunners() {
      const runnerItems = [];
      for (const runner of this.runners) {
        const newItem = {};
        newItem.id = runner.id;
        newItem.isPublic = runner.marathon.isPublic;
        newItem.AvailableCpu = runner.availableResources.cores;
        newItem.AvailableMemory = fileSize(runner.availableResources.memory);        
        runnerItems.push(newItem);
      }
      return runnerItems;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't so much issue with the listing, as it was update function only getting called once in a minute. The final code is for listing runner is bellow.

```
<template>
  <b-col>
    <b-table v-if="runnersTable.length > 0" striped hover :items="runnersTable"></b-table>
  </b-col>
</template>

<script>
const fileSize = require("filesize");
export default {
  name: "RunnersList",
  props: {
    runners: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      haveResourcesLoaded: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {},
  computed: {
    runnersTable() {
      const runnerItems = [];
      for (const runner of this.runners) {
        const newItem = {
          id: runner.id,
          isPublic: runner.marathon.isPublic,
          AvailableCpu: runner.availableResources.cores,
          AvailableMemory: fileSize(runner.availableResources.memory)
        };
        runnerItems.push(newItem);
      }
      return runnerItems;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a really aesthetic solution, but here is a quick workaround:

in your template, add this `v-if` condition:

```
<b-table v-if="haveResourcesLoaded" striped hover :items="formatRunners"></b-table>
```

then in your computed properties, add the corresponding one:

```
haveResourcesLoaded() {
  if (this.runners.length > 0) {
    return this.runners[0].availableResources !== undefined
  }
  return false
}
```

If you need to do it in a better and more controlled way, you should take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/capriza/node-busmq/blob/master/docs/usage.md), the `bus.isOnline()` method might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this takes take of the error. But my main issue is waiting for the variables to change and then display them or have a placeholder before that. As for the bus I'm checking if it's online using a different method, `bus.on('online', () => console.log('BusMQ Online'));
bus.connect();`

Comment: Oh okay I see; are the availableResources ready once the bus is online ? Or does it become online before having all the resources loaded ?

Comment: That's the issue, they aren't, it takes about 10-20 secs. to load availableResources. Once they do they get displayed on the page half a time, other half the page stays blank.

Comment: I suppose my solution doesn’t detect reactively the changes in each runner then... Have you tried using deep watchers ? It will detect nested property changes on your runners.

Comment: I've tried watching the computed value, and then reassign the variables, but that didn't do much.

Comment: I didn’t see your edit on the previous comment, ignore my previous one. So as you say it gets displayed for a few seconds ? Or do you mean that not all runners are displayed ?

Comment: No all runners get displayed as far as I know. Here's the object after the resources [have loaded](https://pasteboard.co/IozzHB9.png). As for your previous comment here's what I had in [watch](https://pastebin.com/GsB5vRr7)

Comment: Here's the page after resources have loaded after a while https://pasteboard.co/IozDKTd.png

Comment: Your watcher watches for foramtRunners and not formatRunners, it might be one of the causes as well - sorry I’m writing on my phone, I can’t test anything right now